# Text parser implemented as a generator

Tags: python, performance, parsing, generator

I often need to parse tab-separated text (usually from a huge file) into records. I wrote a  generator to do that for me; is there anything that could be improved in it, in terms of performance, extensibility or generality?

```
def table_parser(in_stream, types = None, sep = '\t', endl = '\n', comment = None):
  header = next(in_stream).rstrip(endl).split(sep)
  for lineno, line in enumerate(in_stream):
    if line == endl:
      continue # ignore blank lines
    if line[0] == comment:
      continue # ignore comments
    fields = line.rstrip(endl).split(sep)
    try:
      # could have done this outside the loop instead:
      # if types is None: types = {c : (lambda x : x) for c in headers}
      # but it nearly doubles the run-time if types actually is None
      if types is None:
        record = {col : fields[no] for no, col in enumerate(header)}
      else:
        record = {col : types[col](fields[no]) for no, col in enumerate(header)}
    except IndexError:
      print('Insufficient columns in line #{}:\n{}'.format(lineno, line))
      raise
    yield record
```

Comment: @RikPoggi: I asked moderator to move it there. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could try to reduce the amount of code in the loop is to make a function expression for these.

```
  if types is None:
    record = {col : fields[no] for no, col in enumerate(header)}
  else:
    record = {col : types[col](fields[no]) for no, col in enumerate(header)}
```

something like this: *not tested but you should get the idea*

```
def table_parser(in_stream, types = None, sep = '\t', endl = '\n', comment = None):
  header = next(in_stream).rstrip(endl).split(sep)
  enumheader=enumerate(header)              ####  No need to do this every time
  if types is None:
     def recorder(col,fields): 
        return {col : fields[no] for no, col in enumheader}
  else:
     def recorder(col,fields): 
        return {col : types[col](fields[no]) for no, col in enumheader}

  for lineno, line in enumerate(in_stream):
    if line == endl:
      continue # ignore blank lines
    if line[0] == comment:
      continue # ignore comments
    fields = line.rstrip(endl).split(sep)
    try:
        record = recorder(col,fields)
    except IndexError:
      print('Insufficient columns in line #{}:\n{}'.format(lineno, line))
      raise
    yield record
```

EDIT: from my first version (read comments)

```
Tiny thing:

    if types is None:

I suggest

    if not types:
```

Comment: In many cases I think `if types is None` would be preferable. I think I see why you disagree in this case, but I'm curious... could you say more?

Comment: Generally do not test types if it's not clear that it's required. (duck type). In this case I can't come up with a specific benefit, some other type evaluated to false in a boolean context?
Also `is` is testing the identity and would be false even if the other None type was identical to None. Completely academic, yes.

Comment: Well, [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says "Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with 'is' or 'is not', never the equality operators." In this particular case, using `is` makes it possible to distinguish between cases where `[]` was passed and cases where no variable was passed.

Comment: All right that makes sense. From your link: A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds

Answer (score 2):

You also may use csv module to iterate over your file. Your code would be faster because of C implementation and cleaner without `line.rstrip(endl).split(sep)`